# Black square is displaying on screenhot taken by Selenium-JAVA-Chrome and Xvfb

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I am capturing the screenshot using Selenium, JAVA, Chrome and XVFB (on virtual screen), but sometimes (randomly I am getting black square on that screenshot). Please refer below screenshot -

[image: Click here to see sample screenshot]

Could you please help me out.
Thanks.